# How can I list all files with their sizes and date of creation in a specific directory including its sub-directories?

Tags: python

I'm writing a code in Python to list all files with their sizes and date of creation in a specific directory including its sub-directories. The code I ended up with works only for the current directory, but not for a specific directory.
If I replace the value of the variable folder by a specific directory it comes up with an error.

Below is my code:

```
import os, sys, time

folder = "C:\ENTD261"
listOfFiles = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
      for list in files:
       file_size = os.path.getsize(list)
       createDate = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(list))
       listOfFiles = list, "Size: %.1f bytes"%file_size, "Created date: " + createDate
       print(listOfFiles)
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For specific directory, you need to join the root path with the file path for full path.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
for list in files:
    list=os.path.join(root,list) # joining root and the file name for full path
    file_size = os.path.getsize(list)
    createDate = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(list))
    listOfFiles = list, "Size: %.1f bytes"%file_size, "Created date: " + createDate
    print(listOfFiles)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ricky Kim you're a lifesaver. I definitely learned from your code.